# How to test the significance level of two out-of sample regressions with the MSE-F

Tags: regression, f-test

Is there anyone who is experienced in applying the MSE-F (F-test, McCracken, 2007)? 
There are two different values to search for the critical value: $k_2$ and $\pi$.

I was told that $k_2$ equals to the number of parameters included in the regression. But I am not sure how to calculate $\pi$? Is it a ratio of the size of the estimation and evaluation periods?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking, reading McCracken (2007) carefully suggests that

> "$k_2$ is the number of excess parameters" and "The second parameter
>   is $π$, which affects the range of integration"

(M.W. McCracken / Journal of Econometrics 140 (2007) 719-752, p.728)

In other words, $k_2$ is your amount of predictors and $π$ is the ratio $(T-w/w)$, where $w$ is a fixed window size used to generate the forecast and $T$ is your time periods.